# All incoming connections are blocked on OS X

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking

Something is blocking on incoming connections on my Mac and I can't figure out what it is.
Firewall is turned off, anti virus is turned off.

As a simple test, I'm executing:

```
shai@Macbook Downloads $ nc -l 10.0.0.12 12345
```

I can't access it from my iPhone (using the same WiFi hotspot), but when using a browser locally, I see output on netcat - which means connection succeeded.

What is going on?

Comment: As you answered your own question, I suggest you flag this post and ask some kind moderator to undo your bounty, so you can use your reputation in future posts.

Comment: We typically don't do this, but given that the bounty was only started yesterday, consider this a freebie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I decided to go over all of the log files I could find under `/var/logs`.

At some point, I ended up in a log file that contains `DENY/ALLOW` output for incoming connections. I then used `lsof` to figure out who's writing to that file and found the reason for this whole mess: Checkpoint Endpoint security, a VPN client that has a built-in security policy thing.

Comment: Thanks, eventually, I found the same problem, after one day of struggle, and in 2021! I was happening this despite the VPN client (and its Firewall) was disabled. It seems sometimes it leaves things in an inconsistent state: https://community.checkpoint.com/t5/Endpoint/Endpoint-VPN-E82-MacOS-10-15-4-blocks-incoming-connections/td-p/83894

Comment: The app might be called "Endpoint Security VPN" and I can confirm that despite saying its firewall was off, it was indeed blocking incoming connections. Bad engineers. Uninstall it with the script hidden in `/Library/Application Support/Checkpoint/Endpoint Connect/uninstall`

Comment: The problem is fixed in the latest client versions. I had the problem with E82 client and after upgrade to E87 the problem has gone.